# Importing local python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I need some help importing a local python file into another file.

for example I have a file named `calculator.py` and want to import it into another file called `file.py`. When I run the `.py` file it imports (using Hydrogen for atom). However, when I call a function from the file it says it can't be found.

from calculator.py:

```
def addition(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return(c)
```

In another file:

```
import calculator as calc

calc.addition(2,2)
```

Returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d35e30d24b34> in <module>()
----> 1 calc.addition(2,2)

AttributeError: module "calculator" has no attribute "addition"
```

Comment: It looks like you're not importing the correct file. Take a look at the value of `calc.__file__` and confirm that the file path is correct.

Comment: It is importing the correct file path

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the python installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed branches and it seems to work.